# Inserting file into mongo DB using Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to insert the imges into mongo db using meteor frame work . For that i have written this code to create the file object .

```
'change .inputFile': function(event, template) {
FS.Utility.eachFile(event,function(file){
var file=FS.File(file)
alert("file :"+file)
})
```

When i tried to create the file object it is showing this error:

```
TypeError: self.attachData is not a function.
```

Comment: which line throws the error? what have you done to diagnose this? I'm assuming you are using collectionFS? Please elaborate.

Comment: when i tried to convert file into FS file var file=FS.File(file)In this i have not insert to Mongo before that i want to do this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
var file = FS.File(file)
```

This can't work. In the moment you define `file` as a new var the `file` in the right-hand-side is undefined. Try this:

```
'change .inputFile': function(event, template) {
  FS.Utility.eachFile(event,function(file){
    var fileObj = FS.File(file)
    alert("file :", fileObj)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you its working fine .But actually with converting the object i added into DB .FS.Utility.eachFile(events,function(file)
                {
           
                     Uploads.insert(file,function(err){
                      console.log('err'+ err);
                    })
                     
                });